# Inno Setup and VC Redistributable and handling exit code 3010 gracefully

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, vcredist

In my `CurStepChanged` procedure I have some code that installs the Visual Studio Redistributable (if required). Code snippet:

```pascal
if (bVcRedist64BitNeeded) then
begin
    if Exec(ExpandConstant(vcRedist64BitPath), '/install /passive /norestart', '',
            SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then begin
        { handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code }
        Log('VS Redist (64 bit) installer exit code = ' + IntToStr(ResultCode));
        if not (ResultCode = 0) then begin
            MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallFailed,Visual Studio x64 Redistributable}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
            Abort();
        end;
    end
    else begin
        { The execution failed for some reason }
        Log('VS Redist (64 bit) installer exit code = ' + IntToStr(ResultCode));
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Abort();
    end;
end;
```

I had a user saying that the installer for my software was failing so I asked them to send me their logs. At the end of all the logs it had similar to this:

```
2020-09-05 14:37:48.034   VS Redist (64 bit) installer exit code = 3010
2020-09-05 14:37:48.035   Message box (OK):
                          The installation of Visual Studio x64 Redistributable failed. The Meeting Schedule Assistant installation will be aborted.
2020-09-05 14:38:38.352   User chose OK.
2020-09-05 14:38:38.352   CurStepChanged raised an exception.
2020-09-05 14:38:38.353   Need to restart Windows? No
2020-09-05 14:38:38.373   Exception message:
2020-09-05 14:38:38.374   Message box (OK):
                          Internal error: Expression error 'Runtime error (at 191:1960):
                          
                          Exception: Operation aborted.'
2020-09-05 14:38:40.747   User chose OK.
2020-09-05 14:38:40.747   Exception message:
2020-09-05 14:38:40.747   Message box (OK):
                          Internal error: Expression error 'Runtime error (at 191:1960):
                          
                          Exception: Operation aborted.'
2020-09-05 14:38:42.082   User chose OK.
2020-09-05 14:38:42.103   Exception message:
2020-09-05 14:38:42.104   Message box (OK):
                          Out Of Range.
2020-09-05 14:38:44.052   User chose OK.
2020-09-05 14:38:51.259   -- Run entry --
2020-09-05 14:38:51.259   Run as: Original user
2020-09-05 14:38:51.259   Type: Exec
2020-09-05 14:38:51.260   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\MeetSchedAssist.exe
```

I noticed that the redist setup was exiting with a result of `3010`. I can't find any official documentation about the redist exit codes but it seems to be a **soft reboot**. Anyway, today they then tried my installer and it worked (since they had switched their PC of last night):

```
2020-09-06 13:08:38.707   VS Redist (64 bit) installer exit code = 0
2020-09-06 13:09:33.070   VS Redist (32 bit) installer exit code = 0
2020-09-06 13:09:33.071   Need to restart Windows? No
2020-09-06 13:10:07.741   -- Run entry --
2020-09-06 13:10:07.741   Run as: Original user
2020-09-06 13:10:07.741   Type: Exec
2020-09-06 13:10:07.741   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\MeetSchedAssist.exe
```

So I am assuming that 3010 does mean **soft reboot**? And if so, is there a better way we can handle this situation in our Inno Setup installation?

Comment: Here is the list of error codes that I found helpful... https://johnkoerner.com/install/windows-installer-error-codes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the exit code means that the installer needs to restart the machine.

In that case, you can implement [`NeedRestart` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NeedRestart) to request restart, when the exit code was 3010.

Add `NeedRestart` event function and `NeedsRestart` global variable:

```pascal
var
  NeedsRestart: Boolean;

function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := NeedsRestart;
end;
```

And modify your exit code testing logic to:

```pascal
if ResultCode = 3010 then
begin
  Log('Need restart');
  NeedsRestart := True;
end
  else
if ResultCode <> 0 then
begin
  MsgBox(
    ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallFailed,Visual Studio x64 Redistributable}'),
    mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Abort();
end;
```

---

*Similar question: [How to restart Inno Setup installer based on result of procedure that executes a program/subinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74742659/850848)*